# Plot a piecewise stream plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot, graph

I need to plot a piecewise stream plot, where my vector field is defined by

```
def f(x):
    if x<= 2:
        return 5/((3-2*(-x))**2)-((-18+(-x))*(-6+(-x)))/((-x)**4)
    else:
        return 5/((3-2*x)**2)-((-18+x)*(-6+x))/(x**4)

u = y

v = f(x)
```

How could I perform this plotting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`np.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) to define the function and [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = 3
y, x = np.mgrid[-w:w:100j, -w:w:100j]

U = y

V = np.piecewise(x, [x <= 2, x > 2], [lambda x: 5/((3-2*(-x))**2)-((-18+(-x))*(-6+(-x)))/((-x)**4), lambda x: 5/((3-2*x)**2)-((-18+x)*(-6+x))/(x**4)])

plt.streamplot(x, y, U, V, density=[0.5, 1])

plt.show()
```

Gives us the following plot:

[image]